# Is there a way to enforce a Map object has all literals of "a union type of literals" as keys, in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, custom-type, es6-map

I want to create a type which is a Map has all possible literals of a string literal union type.

For example:

```js
type TNumberNames =
  | 'one'
  | 'two'
  | 'three'

const numberMap: MyMapType = new Map().set('one', 1).set('two', 2).set('three', 3);
// this Map object should have all literals in TNumberNames!
```

I already found a way in Object instead of Map:

```js
const numberRecord: Record<TNumberNames, number> = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3,
};
```

in above example, if `three` is removed in `numberRecord`, TS compiler shows an error.

How do I declare `MyMapType` to do like this for Map object?

Comment: you can declare a map like `const map = new Map<"a" | "b" | "c", number>()` but it will never be *required* to have a value for each key.

Comment: I am going to replace `Required<TNumberNames>` with just `TNumberNames` in your example; `Required<>` isn't doing what you think it's doing here, and leaving it this way is distracting from your question.

Comment: What do you plan to do with such a `RequiredMap` type?  One could possibly implement that like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8BvVm)... does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?